# Can I use Chi^2 to test significance in frequencies of three groups?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, python, chi-squared-test, frequency

I have conducted fieldwork on tree seedlings in plots with different treatments: natural, managed, and fertilised.
The dataset consists of the frequency at which the different tree species occur. I got this for every year:

```
Sp     Freq     Year     Treatment
NS     10.3     2000     N
PO     20.4     2000     N
Be      2.7     2000     N
...
...
...
NS     11.3     2020     F
PO     17.3     2020     F
Be     10.9     2020     F
```

I also have this as an overall mean for the years 2000-2020:

```
Sp     Freq     Year     Treatment
NS     12.6     2010     N
Po     16.4     2010     N
Be      7.7     2010     N
Bi     11.1     2010     N
NS     13.6     2010     M
Po     15.4     2010     M
Be      9.7     2010     M
Bi     13.1     2010     M
NS     15.6     2010     F
Po     19.4     2010     F
Be     10.7     2010     F
Bi     14.1     2010     F
...
```

I want to test if the frequencies are significantly different between tree species per treatment. I have read that I can use a Chi<sup>2</sup> for testing these differences. If so, I assume I am comparing annual data since the overall mean would result in comparison of 1 entry vs. 1 entry.
I started the coding in python:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import chi2_contingency

#Frequencies of tree species in three stands over 21 years
stand_n = [12.6, 16.4, 7.7, 11.1]  #Frequencies of tree species in Stand N
stand_m = [13.6, 15.4, 9.7, 13.1]  #Frequencies of tree species in Stand M
stand_f = [15.6, 19.4, 10.7, 14.1]  #Frequencies of tree species in Stand F

#Create a 2D array representing the contingency table
#Rows correspond to the stands (N, M, and F), and columns correspond to the categories
contingency_table = np.array([stand_n, stand_m, stand_f])

#Perform the chi-square test for independence
chi2, p, dof, expected = chi2_contingency(contingency_table)

#Print the results
print("Chi-square statistic:", chi2)
print("p-value:", p)
print("Degrees of freedom:", dof)
print("Expected frequencies:")
print(expected)
```

Here, I used the overall mean, but should I do it differently or should I use a completely different statistical test?

Comment: $\chi^2$ test is for categorial data. As the response is numeric in your case, you can use ANOVA. Moreover, you only have one factor (the treatment) so that you can drop the assumption of equal variances inherent to ANOVA by using Welsh's variant of ANOVA instead, which is `oneway.test()` in R.

Comment: You would typically use the $\chi^2$ test for contingency tables on the original counts, not on frequencies. Your frequencies don't add up to 100%. Do you have an "other" category? The raw counts would give you a $3\times 5$ contingency table that you could run your $\chi^2$ test on.